# iOS App Clip getting query parameters from URL that launched it

Tags: swift, apple-appclips

Is there anyway to get the query parameters from the url that launched an iOS App Clip? Tried searching this topic but found little info on the matter.

Comment: Did you find any doc about this, I am also searching for the same.

Comment: @AitreyaVerma Found the solution in the following apple documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/responding_to_invocations